# Java - Remove all elements if attribute is included in a comma-seperated string

Tags: java, jdom

I am modifying a legacy code and I need to remove all elements if its id attribute is included in a string.

Example ids to remove:

```
String idToExclude = "2,4,6,8,10";
```

Assuming `Element doc` contains the following:

```
<StoreOffers>
    <Store StoreID="0">
        <Offers>
            <Offer OfferID="1"/>
            <Offer OfferID="2"/>
            <Offer OfferID="3"/>
            <Offer OfferID="4"/>
            <Offer OfferID="5"/>
            <Offer OfferID="6"/>
            <Offer OfferID="7"/>
            <Offer OfferID="8"/>
            <Offer OfferID="9"/>
            <Offer OfferID="10"/>
        </Offers>
    </Store>
</StoreOffers>
```

**EDIT**
This is what I've tried, this is the actual code. I've updated the xml as well:

```
String offersToExclude = getOffersToExclude(customer);

                    StringReader asa = new StringReader(storeOffers);
                    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
                    Document doc = builder.build(asa);
                    Element root = doc.getRootElement();
                    List<Element> stores = root.getChildren();

                    for (Element store : stores) {
                        storeid = store.getAttributeValue("StoreID");
                        List<Element> offers = store.getChild("Offers").getChildren();

                        for(Element offer : offers) {
                            String offerid = offer.getAttributeValue("OfferID");

                            if(CCSUtils.isNotEmpty(offerid)) {
                                if(offersToExclude.contains(offerid)) {
                                    store.getChild("Offers").removeChild(offer); //This doesn't work
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried already

Comment: Please see my edit post @YoavGur

Comment: You can try this method of jdom
removeContent(Filter<F> filter)

Comment: I wonder why but removeContent is also depreciated. Should I just suppress those warnings?

Comment: Please edit your code to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And what is the version of jdom you used?

Comment: please include your jdom version?

Comment: I'm trying to get the jdom version but `java -cp jdom.jar jdomabout` doesn't seem to work. Are there any other way to get the version? Tried extracting it via 7zip but the file on meta folder only shows version 1.

Comment: @Cyberpau, Can you find META-INF folder after extracting the jar? If yes, see if there is any file inside containing the version info.

Comment: yes, I've seen the meta-inf folder but the only file is `MANIFEST.MF` and when opened with notepad, it says `Manifest-Version: 1.0`. The modified date was 2000-10-07, I hope it helped. @samabcde

Comment: I tried version jdom 1.1.3 with your code(I can not guess all the type from your code) but cannot compile, please try to create a complete class with main method that can demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Hi @samabcde sorry for the late reply. I'm trying to fix it as well. Please see updated codes.

Comment: @Cyberpau, I still get compile error : `The method removeChild(String) in the type Element is not applicable for the arguments (Element)` using your updated code. Can you also describe the error/problem you found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Since the version of `jdom` is not known, the following solution is base on version 2.0.6 (latest as at 29/10/2018).*

First, the method `removeChild` is not applicable for `String` argument, there is only two method: `public boolean removeChild(final String cname)` and `public boolean removeChild(final String cname, final Namespace ns)`.

To achieve what you expected, simply manipulate the elements get from `Element.getChildren()` method of the parent `Element`. As explained in [Java Doc](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Element.html#getChildren()) of `Element.getChildren()`

> This returns a List of all the child elements nested directly (one level deep) within this element, as Element objects. If this target element has no nested elements, an empty List is returned. **The returned list is "live"in document order and changes to it affect the element's actual contents**.
>
> Sequential traversal through the List is best done with a Iterator since the underlying implement of List.size() may not be the most efficient.

So we can use the iterator to iterate the child elements, and remove the element if the OfferID is one of our target. The following code demonstrate how this can be done.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom2.output.Format;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;

public class DeleteChild {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JDOMException {
        // Should not use String.contains method as OfferId="1" will be deleted.
        String[] offersToExclude = "2,4,6,8,10".split(",");

        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(getXml());
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.build(stringReader);
        Element root = doc.getRootElement();
        System.out.println("*****Before Remove*****");
        System.out.println(new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat(), null).outputString(root));
        List<Element> stores = root.getChildren();

        for (Element store : stores) {
            List<Element> offers = store.getChild("Offers").getChildren();
            Iterator<Element> offerIterator = offers.iterator();
            while (offerIterator.hasNext()) {
                Element offer = offerIterator.next();
                if (Arrays.asList(offersToExclude).contains(offer.getAttributeValue("OfferID"))) {
                    offerIterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("*****After Remove*****");
        System.out.println(new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat(), null).outputString(root));
    }

    private static String getXml() {
        return "   <StoreOffers>                                          "
                + "    <Store StoreID=\"0\">                              "
                + "        <Offers>                                       "
                + "        <Offer OfferID=\"1\"/>                         "
                + "        <Offer OfferID=\"2\"/>                         "
                + "        <Offer OfferID=\"3\"/>                         "
                + "        <Offer OfferID=\"4\"/>                         "
                + "        <Offer OfferID=\"5\"/>                         "
                + "        <Offer OfferID=\"6\"/>                         "
                + "        <Offer OfferID=\"7\"/>                         "
                + "        <Offer OfferID=\"8\"/>                         "
                + "        <Offer OfferID=\"9\"/>                         "
                + "        <Offer OfferID=\"10\"/>                        "
                + "        </Offers>                                      "
                + "    </Store>                                           "
                + "</StoreOffers>                                         ";
    }
}
```